# How can I change the way of selecting in a checkbox?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, autocomplete, material-ui

I'm using react and I have a checkbox created with Autocomplete where I select items. It
is the same as that provided by material:

The problem is that the function "OnChange" runs only if I select the square.
I would like it to work also by selecting the row. How can I do it? Here's my code:

```
<AutoComplete
          multiple
          id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
          options={props.roles}
          // disableCloseOnSelect
          // getOptionLabel={(options) => `${options}`}
          renderOption={(options, { selected }) => (
            <React.Fragment>
              <Checkbox
                icon={icon}
                checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
                style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
                value={options}
                checked={selected}
                onChange={updateNewRoles}
              />
              {options}
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
          style={{ width: 500 }}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              variant="outlined"
              label=""
              placeholder="Available Roles"
            />
          )}
        />
        <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmitChecked}>
          Save
        </button>
```

This is a photo of the example provided by material. The functions are performed only by clicking the icon and not the line:

[image: example provided by material]

Comment: Which row ? Can you add an codesandbox to see your example working ?

Comment: Of course, I insert a photo to make you understand what I mean

Comment: It works if you click the row.

Comment: the insertion of the selected element in the box works but the function in "OnChange" is performed only by clicking the icon. In the "updateNewRoles" function I pass the event, this event is recognized only by clicking on the icon